# How to get data in xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt

I have `XML` code like this:

```
    <hotels>
    <hotel contact="(855) 23 430 732">
        <name>hotel A</name>
        <type>hotel or apartment</type>
        <rating>1 to 5</rating>
        <address>
            <houseNo>73 </houseNo>
            <street>Preah Monivong Blvd </street>
            <Sangkat>Mean Chey</Sangkat >
            <Khan>Daun Penh</Khan>
            <city>Bangkok</city>
        </address>
        <room>
            <roomType>hotel: standard/deluxe, apartment: studio/2-bedroom/3-bedroom</roomType>
            <price>209</price>
            <description>Descriptions</description>
        </room>
        <room>
            <roomType>hotel: standard/deluxe, apartment: studio/2-bedroom/3-bedroom</roomType>
            <price>210</price>
            <description>Descriptions</description>
        </room>
        <room>
            .....
        </room>
    </hotel>
    <hotel contact="...">
        ... ...
        ... ...
    </hotel>
</hotels>
```

Using `xsl` code how I can read it? This is my code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
     <h2>test xsl</h2>
     <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
           <th style="text-align:left;">Name</th>
           <th style="text-align:left;">Type</th>
           <th style="text-align:left;">Rating</th>
           <th style="text-align:left;">Address</th>
           <th style="text-align:left;">Room</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="hotels/hotel">
        <tr>
        <!--<xsl:value-of select="."/>--> 
           <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="type" /></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="rating" /></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="address" /></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="room" /></td>
       </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
     </table>
     </body>
   </html>
 </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**problem**My code is nothing errors but for `<room>` can load only first child. Any one has experience with `xsl` please help me to solve it

**I wish result like [image: this] **

Comment: Please post a complete stylesheet **and** the expected result. -- **Hint**: you need to use another `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:apply-templates` in order to process the rooms.

Comment: Please check it again, I edit ready

Comment: I still don't see the expected result. You are creating a row for each hotel: how do you expect to show multiple rooms in a single row?

Comment: yes, I want if it's have many room, show it by `-` or anything can user know acceptable

Comment: Please post the expected result as code. [3]

Comment: please check my edit again, this image is what i want but my code not reach it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="room" /></td>
```

to:

```
<td>
    <xsl:for-each select="room">
        <xsl:text>- </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="roomType" />
        <xsl:text> Price: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="price" />
        <xsl:text> Description: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="description" />
        <br/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</td>
```

---

Personally, I would prefer to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/hotels">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>test xsl</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Rating</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Room Type</th>
                    <th>Room Price</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="hotel"/>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="hotel">
    <xsl:variable name="rowspan" select="count(room) + 1" />
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="{$rowspan}"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>   
        <td rowspan="{$rowspan}"><xsl:value-of select="type"/></td>   
        <td rowspan="{$rowspan}"><xsl:value-of select="rating"/></td>   
        <td rowspan="{$rowspan}"><xsl:value-of select="address"/></td>   
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="room"/>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="room">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="roomType"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to get:

[image]

Comment: Could I know how to `var_dump` as `PHP` in ` <xsl:for-each>` or not for view data that we load. I really don't know how to debug it.

Comment: @Songs I don't understand what you're asking. It seems unrelated to this question or to XSLT in general. I suggest you start a new question.

Comment: I am low in `stackoverflow`, how to accept answer ? I vote up ready

Comment: yes it's not related but I just want you share me some experience with debug `xsl` code

Comment: As I said, I don't understand the question. If it's about PHP,  I don't know the answer.