# How I can write XSL code to list data with condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have `XML` code like this

```
    <hotels>
    <hotel>
        <name>hotel A</name>
        <rating>5</rating>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
        <name>hotel B</name>
        <rating>4</rating>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
        <name>hotel C</name>
        <rating>2</rating>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
        ....
    </hotel>
</hotels>
```

By My old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34390587/how-to-get-data-in-xsl-file), How I can write `XSL` code in file .xsl to list data with condition `rating` >=4 ;

Comment: Please post self-contained questions and include the XML input, a complete stylesheet and the expected output. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

If you are using:

```
<xsl:for-each select="hotels/hotel">
```

change it to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="hotels/hotel[rating >= 4]">
```

---

If you are using:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="hotel"/>
```

change it to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="hotel[rating >= 4]"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting all hotel names with a rating >= 4 in one template:

```
<xsl:template match="hotels/hotel/name[../rating >= 4]">
   ...
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Beware of the built-in templates.